# How to get multiple windows to perform the same menu item action?

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nswindowcontroller, nsmenuitem

I have a `Cocoa` app which supports multiple windows.

I already know how to get the main window to perform actions for any of the `NSMenuItem` from `NSMenu` and including the `NSToolbarItem` from the `NSToolbar`.

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    // ...
    @IBAction func doSomethingIncredible(_ sender: Any?) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That is easy for a single window app but my app supports multiple windows.

But how can I get other windows apart from the main window to access and even validate the `NSMenuItem` from `NSMenu`?

An example of this is Safari. It supports multiple windows. You can select *Open Location...(⌘L), New Tab (⌘T), Show Sidebar (⇧⌘L)* etc. It does the action on the focused window. It is not tied to the main window. It can be done on any windows. How can I do this for my app?

```
class AnotherWindowController: NSWindowController {
    // ...
    @IBAction func doSomethingIncredible(_ sender: Any?) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can the `MainWindowController` and the `AnotherWindowController` perform the same action from one of the `NSMenuItem` from `NSMenu` when one of them is the key focused window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than *hard-connecting* the menu item to a specific controller connect it to the First Responder (the red cube).

The first object in the responder chain which responds to the seclector – usually the frontmost window – catches the action and executes it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This made understand first responder much better in the context of multiple windows than a single window.